# split some string items in a list by a particular word in python

Tags: python, string, list

i have a list which contains some string items

```
res = ["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'"]
```

i want to iterate over all list items and

1.remove a word phrase if start with count_     (in between two & character)

out put should be like

```
res = ["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'"]
```

i have tried something like

```
for x in res:
    regex = re.compile('count_')   #setting a search cateory
    matches = [string for string in res if re.match(regex, string)]  # finding all matches
    resfinal = [x for x in res if x not in matches]
```

But not successful.  I know i am missing some reg operation  tricks ,but not getting it. Please suggest with some codelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex.

```
>>> res = ["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'"]
>>> [' & '.join(x for x in i.split(' & ') if not x.startswith('count_')) for i in res]
["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'", "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'"]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`re.match()` == `re.search('^regex')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)

So `re.match(regex, string)` will check if the string is starts with `count_`, not search in in the string. So you should use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`:

```
for x in res:
    regex = re.compile('count_')   #setting a search cateory
    matches = [string for string in res if re.search(regex, string)]  # finding all matches
    resfinal = [x for x in res if x not in matches]
```

Output:

```
["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'",
 "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'"]
```

But `if x not in matches` will remove the string if there's `count_` in it. I think you should use:

```
>>> import re
>>> res = ["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'",
... "FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'"]

>>> for x in res:
...     resfinal = [re.sub(' & count_.*(?= & )', '', x) for x in res]  # remove all things after that ` & count_`
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in resfinal:
...     print(i)
...     
... 
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'
>>>
```

Comment: @Kevin-if there is something more after the count_ phrase end then your code is deleting that part also...for example res = ["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1 & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS'"]

Comment: @Satya: Oops, forgot that. What about know? Added a `(?= & )`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong datatype. Consider trying to build a list of dicts if you want to extract any more information from these strings. If you insist on keeping your list items strings, try this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'( &|^)\s*count_.*?(& |$)')
new_res = []
for line in res:
    match = regex.search(line)
    if match:
        groups = match.groups()
        replacement = groups[0] if groups[0] and groups[1] else ''
        new_res.append(
            line[:m.start()] + replacement + line[m.end():]
        )
    else:
        new_res.append(line)
res = new_res
del new_res
```

The magic is in the regular expression. It matches ' &' or the beginning of a string, then only space characters until 'count_', then anything else and finally a finishing '& ' or the end of the string. '*?' is to make sure it makes a match as small as possible.